# JS: Insert youtubelink=youtube info

Tags: javascript, jquery

So ive got this far:

```
$.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/NWHfY_lvKIQ?v=2&alt=json', function(data) {
        var title = data.entry.title.$t;
        var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
        var thumbnail = data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url; // URL of the image

        alert (description);
                alert (title);
                        alert (thumbnail);
        // Use these variables somewhere
});
```

This script is for one specific video.

Now i want this same thing to happen but that you insert a youtube link and then this happens.

e.g you paste this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7YXn-lfHXc into a normal `<input id="youtubebox" type="text">` , then it will give you those three alerts with the description, title and thumbnail for the videolink you've inserted.

So it converts somehow this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7YXn-lfHXc to this G7YXn-lfHXc and then inserts that videolink ID at this line:

$.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/**HERE**?v=2&alt=json', function(data) {

Or? how can i do this please help me my last needs for my system, thank you.

Comment: What do you need help on? Your code works fine.

Comment: I want so when you paste a youtube videolink in a box on my page, it runs this code with the pasted videolink´s ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED with some more validation to avoid returning errors with invalid data (eg wrong youtube link)**

This will take care of it for you.

You could place the event on a button or as is "on blur" of the input field

```
<input type="text" name="youtube" id="youtube_url" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#youtube_url").blur(function() {
            var url=$(this).val();
            //get the youtube video id
            regx = new RegExp("http://(www.)?youtube.com/(.*)v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)");
            var ytID = regx.exec(url);

            if(ytID!=null && ytID[3]!="") {
                $.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+ytID[3]+'?v=2&alt=json', function(data) {
                        if(data.entry != null) {                                                                         
                            var title = data.entry.title.$t;
                            var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
                            var thumbnail = data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url; // URL of the image

                            alert (description);
                            alert (title);
                            alert (thumbnail);
                        // Use these variables somewhere
                        }
                });
            }
    });                        
});
</script>
```

Comment: You rock, thank you, and not for the source but that i now understand how to do this next timee

Comment: No probs. The only real tricky thing is the regular expression. Glad I could help.